# How to extract session id from response in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

How can I extract the session id from response?

```
{"game_url":"https://nogs-gl-stage.nyxmalta.com/game/?nogsgameid=110004&nogsoperatorid=421&sessionid=2007_a87178f4-a398-46f9-b156-a05da5040a37&nogscurrency=EUR&nogslang=en_us&nogsmode=real&accountid=7116&clienttype=html5&lobbyurl=https%3A%2F%2F%2Flobby%2Ffeatured-games",
 "non_regulated_game":"NON_REGULATED_GAME_MESSAGE"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example configuration would be:

1. Add [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns the above response
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, u.e. `sessionid`
   - Regular Expression: `sessionid=(.+?)&`
   - Template: `$1$`
3. Refer extracted value as `${sessionid}` or `${__V(sessionid)}` where required later on

You can also use "RegEx Tester" view of the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to test your regular expressions without having to re-run the request:

[image: JMeter View Results Tree Regex Tester]

References:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) With JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)